# Apache Shiro login failed using JDBC Realm

Tags: apache, authentication, shiro, jdbcrealm

I am trying to connect to oracle DB .
I want to retrieve list of passwords from data base using the authentication query. Here is my sample shiro.ini file:

```
# password matcher
passwordMatcher = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher
passwordService = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService
passwordMatcher.passwordService = $passwordService

# datasource
ds = oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
ds.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@matrix-oracle11g:1521:dev11g
ds.user = cit1am
ds.password = cit1

jdbcRealm = org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm
jdbcRealm.permissionsLookupEnabled = true
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT USR_PSWD FROM USR
jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $passwordMatcher
jdbcRealm.dataSource = $ds
securityManager.realms = $jdbcRealm
[users]

[roles]

[urls]
```

Sample code snippet of login:

```
public class Quickstart {

    private static final transient Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Quickstart.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Factory<SecurityManager> factory = new IniSecurityManagerFactory("classpath:shiro.ini");
        SecurityManager securityManager = factory.getInstance();
        SecurityUtils.setSecurityManager(securityManager);
        Subject currentUser = SecurityUtils.getSubject();

        // Do some stuff with a Session (no need for a web or EJB container!!!)
        Session session = currentUser.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("someKey", "aValue");
        String value = (String) session.getAttribute("someKey");
        if (value.equals("aValue")) {
            log.info("Retrieved the correct value! [" + value + "]");
        }
        try{
        // let's login the current user so we can check against roles and permissions:
        if (!currentUser.isAuthenticated()) {

            UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken("cit1am", "cit1")   ;
            token.setRememberMe(true);
            try {
                currentUser.login(token); //problem occurs here 
                log.info("inside try block ==========>>" );
            }
catch (UnknownAccountException uae) {
                log.info("There is no user with username of " + token.getPrincipal());
            }
```

I am getting following error:

```
    [main] ERROR org.apache.shiro.realm.jdbc.JdbcRealm - There was a SQL error while authenticating user [cit1am]
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:445)
```

Please suggest what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging more i found issue with my code and sql query in .ini file. 
I changed following in .INI file

```
jdbcRealm.authenticationQuery = SELECT USR_PSWD FROM USR where USR_NM = ?
Also commented
#cm = org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.Sha256CredentialsMatcher
#jdbcRealm.credentialsMatcher = $cm and removedconfiguration related to password matcher
```

I also removed role and permission check from java code.

As i have just started with shrio it's bit difficult to understand flow at start.
Though it can help some one in future.

Thanks

Comment: Yeah man, I am hitting my head of the fall with this. So tired of the obfuscated JAVA ecosystem. PHP frameworks are much easier.